# Riot-iOS Error: while run bundle exec pod install

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, bundle

I have tried to run a [project](https://github.com/vector-im/riot-ios)

So, I download a files and run a build instructions.
When I run a

> bundle exec pod install

is showing error. I can't able to understand. Please help me.

[image]

After that I have run below commands

> brew update
>
> brew install cmake

Now error was showing like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this question and now workspace was created.

Before I run this command `bundle exec` have to run `Xcode-select`

Like

> sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>
> bundle exec pod install